# Validation of Transactions Executed in on_finalised Function within the Hook

Tags: transactions, validator, finality, hook

Will transactions executed within the on_finalised function inside the hook undergo validation by the validators?

Answer (score 4):

You mean `on_finalize`? There are no transactions executed in that.
It is called by the block author to finalize the built block.

But all state changes that happen in there are guarded by consensus and are thereby validated. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: So if we doing some storage updation inside the `on_finalize` that will validated by the validators. right?

Comment: Yea. Same as `on_initialize`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help